# Access SQL Sub Query Returns 0 when in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm running the following SQL in an Access Database, and results are returned from the sub queries.

```
Select b.PlannedDescription ,

        (SELECT SUM(c.PlannedAmount) FROM DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION c
        WHERE(c.PlannedDate)>=#2018/08/01# And (c.PlannedDate)<=#2018/09/05#
        And c.PlannedDescription = b.PlannedDescription
        And (c.PlannedType)='P'
        ) AS [Planned],

        (SELECT SUM(a.PlannedAmount) As Amount FROM DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION A
        WHERE(a.PlannedDate)>=#2018/08/01# And (a.PlannedDate)<=#2018/09/05#
        And a.PlannedDescription = b.PlannedDescription
        And (a.PlannedType)='A'
        ) AS [Actual]

        From DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION As b
        Where ((b.PlannedType) ='A' AND (b.PlannedDate)>=#2018/08/01# And (b.PlannedDate)<=#2018/09/05#)
        GROUP BY b.PlannedDescription
```

When i run it in Visual Studio, the sub queries return 0?

```
Public Sub uspLoad(ByVal DateFrom As Date, ByVal DateTo As Date)

        ds.Tables.Add("tbComparison")
        ds.Tables("tbComparison").Columns.Add("PlannedDescription", GetType(String))
        ds.Tables("tbComparison").Columns.Add("Planned", GetType(Decimal))
        ds.Tables("tbComparison").Columns.Add("Actual", GetType(Decimal))

        Dim connectionString As String = My.Settings.ConnString
        Dim sql As String =
                "Select b.PlannedDescription,

        (SELECT SUM(c.PlannedAmount) FROM DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION c
        WHERE(c.PlannedDate)>=#" & Format(DateFrom, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "# And (c.PlannedDate)<=#" & Format(DateTo, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "#
        And c.PlannedDescription = b.PlannedDescription
        And (c.PlannedType)='P'
        ) AS [Planned],

        (SELECT SUM(a.PlannedAmount) FROM DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION A
        WHERE(a.PlannedDate)>=#" & Format(DateFrom, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "# And (a.PlannedDate)<=#" & Format(DateTo, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "#
        And a.PlannedDescription = b.PlannedDescription
        And (a.PlannedType)='A'
        ) AS [Actual]

        From DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION As b
        Where ((b.PlannedType) ='A' AND (b.PlannedDate)>=#" & Format(DateFrom, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "# And (b.PlannedDate)<=#" & Format(DateTo, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "#)
        GROUP BY b.PlannedDescription"

        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)

        connection.Open()
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "tbComparison")
        connection.Close()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tbComparison")
```

I have tried casting the returned values but it still doesn't work. I also thought it might be the datagridview, but the dataset is also returning zeros. Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Have you tried using date parameters so you dont have to try and manually format the dates? Also, rather than doing sub queries can you do a single pass through the table, and use a construct like `sum(case when <condition> then PlannedAmount else 0 end) as Planned`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your version of VS, in the newest versione of it, you can continue your string on the next line without doing anything, but it's always better to specify that you want to continue your command on the next line, so here is your code fixed:

```
 Dim sql As String = "Select b.PlannedDescription," & _
    " (SELECT SUM(c.PlannedAmount) FROM DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION c" & _
    " WHERE(c.PlannedDate)>=#" & Format(DateFrom, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "# And (c.PlannedDate)<=#" & Format(DateTo, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "#" & _
    " And c.PlannedDescription = b.PlannedDescription" & _
    " And (c.PlannedType)='P'" & _
    " ) AS [Planned]," & _
    " (SELECT SUM(a.PlannedAmount) FROM DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION A" & _
    "WHERE(a.PlannedDate)>=#" & Format(DateFrom, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "# And (a.PlannedDate)<=#" & Format(DateTo, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "#" & _
    " And a.PlannedDescription = b.PlannedDescription" & _
    " And (a.PlannedType)='A'" & _
    " ) AS [Actual]" & _
    " From DT_PLANNED_TRANSACTION As b" & _
    " Where ((b.PlannedType) ='A' AND (b.PlannedDate)>=#" & Format(DateFrom, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "# And (b.PlannedDate)<=#" & Format(DateTo, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "#)" & _
    " GROUP BY b.PlannedDescription"
```